# "expected parenthesis" error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code in my bash script:

```
if [[ "$USE_NEW" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Forcing usage of NEW build script"
    ./android/build/build.new.sh $@
elif [[ $MAJOR > 4 || ($MAJOR = 4 && $MINOR >= 2) ]]; then
    echo "Version greater than or equal to 4.2.x.x, running NEW build script"
    ./android/build/build.new.sh $@
else
    echo "Version less than 4.2.x.x, running LEGACY build script"
    #./android/build/build.legacy.sh $@
fi
```

I get an error:

```
line 149: expected `)'
```

Line 149 here happens to be the line containing the first `elif` in my example above. I don't know much about bash scripting and I can't find anything via Google that helps me find out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help correct my bash script?

Comment: Try putting spaces around the parens. Bash is very particular about separating tokens with whitespace in certain cases.

Comment: It's not easy to Google syntax errors. Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) instead (as described in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)), which automatically points out your problem.

Comment: @nneonneo: The problem here is not spaces. The problem is that `>=` is not a valid conditional operator, so it is actually parsed as though it were: `$MINOR > = 4`. Some operator is needed between the `=` and the `4` to make this a valid expression, so bash reports a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your 2nd condition to:

```
[[ "$MAJOR" -gt 4 || ( "$MAJOR" -eq 4 && "$MINOR" -ge 2 ) ]]
```

**EDIT:** Or better:

```
(( MAJOR > 4 || ( MAJOR == 4 && MINOR >= 2) ))
```

Comment: Or better yet, `(( MAJOR > 4 || ( MAJOR == 4 && MINOR >= 2) ))` - make use of arithmetic syntax when you're doing arithmetic... Of course, it might also then be a good idea to check that `$MAJOR` and `$MINOR` are actually numbers before-hand - but if they're not, even the `-gt` syntax is going to have issues...

Comment: Thanks @twalberg: I added that to my answer

Comment: Why is there a space after the first `(` after the `||`?

Comment: Even `(( MAJOR > 4 || (MAJOR == 4 && MINOR >= 2) ))` should also work

Comment: Thanks. Why do you not need to expand the variables like `$MAJOR`?

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question. If you're asking about quoting I did it for the case when variables are empty.

Comment: @RobertDailey The extra spaces inside the `(( ... ))` are cosmetic for readability and not required. Also, inside an arithmetic context, shell variables do not need to have the `$` to dereference them (although including it is perfectly valid as well).

Comment: So basically my understanding now is that `(( ... ))` is needed for integral comparisons, and everything else (string, file comparisons) use `[[ ... ]]`. Is this correct? Also not sure what would happen if you mix integral with string comparisons.

Comment: Yes `((...))` is for BASH arithmetic (no floating point though) only. You cannot do string comparisons inside `((...))` (those variables with string values will be treated as zero)

Comment: @RobertDailey I wouldn't necessarily say that `(( ... ))` is *needed* for integral comparisons - `[[ 10 -gt 1 ]]` still works - but it does make a lot of arithmetic constructs more convenient as long as you are using `bash` (since it's a `bash`-ism, if you're concerned about portability to other shells, stick with the `[ ... ]` forms). There are different parsing rules inside `(( ... ))` that make it more convenient in many cases.